# Definições e uso da mesmas em classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quando eu crio uma "`def`" pelo o que eu entendi é diferente de `__init__` certo?
Se eu crio um objeto no `__init__` é possível acessa-lo de outras `def`'s? Em alguns códigos eu reparei que usam '`self.objeto`' mesmo em outras `def`s. A minha dúvida é se quando eu crio o objeto dentro da `def` ele é válido para toda a classe?

Comment: Lucas, você poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais informações? De preferência com exemplos de código para a gente entender seu problema (confesso que me confundiu a maneira como está escrito).

Answer (score 2):

Depende.

No Python você perceberá que para os métodos de instância (que não são estáticos ou de classe), o primeiro parâmetro sempre¹ se chamará `self`. Este objeto é uma referência para a própria instância que você está trabalhando quando o método é invocado. Todos os métodos da classe possuirão a referência ao mesmo objeto e, portanto, qualquer alteração que você fizer nele em um método será refletido em todos os outros.

Por exemplo, se eu fizer:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.idade = 0
```

Eu estarei modificando o objeto `self` definindo um novo campo chamado `idade` e atribuindo-lhe o valor zero. Se eu criar outro método que utiliza este valor:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.idade = 0

    def get_idade(self):
        return self.idade
```

O valor de `self.idade` ainda será 0, pois `self` será o mesmo objeto entre os dois métodos.

Porém, se você não define os valores em `self`, estas alterações pertencerão apenas ao escopo local. Por exemplo, ao invés de fazer `self.idade` fazer apenas `idade`:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self):
        idade = 0

    def get_idade(self):
        return self.idade
```

O objeto `idade` só existirá no escopo de `__init__` e não existirá no `get_idade`.

Em termos de classes e objetos, sempre que o valor representar um novo estado do objeto você deverá armazená-lo em `self`. Se o valor for auxiliar ou temporário, utilize variáveis locais.

---

¹: Não é sempre, pois o parâmetro pode receber qualquer nome, mas por convenção e em 99% das vezes será `self`.

Comment: Compreendi a parte que alterando um objeto com self altera ele para toda a classe, só não ficou completamente claro um ponto para mim. Posso criar mais de um objeto self?
Por exemplo: 


class pessoa:
 def __init__(self):
  self.idade = 0
  self.sexo = ''
  self.endereco = ''

Comment: Sim, mas não é a nomenclatura correta. O `self` será o mesmo objeto, o que você estará criando são campos nele e campos você pode criar quantos precisar.